# multiple marker in Google Map V2 using InfoWindowAdapter

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

I'm using google Map V2 in my android project.I've used multiple marker in the Map and I've used InfoWindowAdapter, for every marker I recuperate position of the marker and a picture from the database. But the problem is that only one picture appears(related to the last marker).

this is a part of my code :

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_geolocalisation);


       Intent i = getIntent();
       String LesAgents = (String)i.getSerializableExtra("LesAgentAssocies");

       try {
         json = new JSONArray(LesAgents);

    } catch (JSONException e) {      
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

       map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();



       for (int j = 0; j < json.length(); j++) {
           initImageLoader();
           markers = new Hashtable<String, String>();
           try {
            JSONObject agent = json.getJSONObject(j);
            String pseudo = agent.getString("pseudo");
            double longitude =    
                         Double.parseDouble(agent.getString("longitude"));
            double latitude = 
                         Double.parseDouble(agent.getString("latitude"));
            String image = agent.getString("image");
            String imagePath = image.substring(1, image.length()); 

            markers = new Hashtable<String, String>();
            imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

            options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showStubImage(R.drawable.ic_launcher)         
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_launcher)     
            .cacheInMemory()
            .cacheOnDisc().bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565).build();

            if (map!=null){
    map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomInfoWindowAdapter());
      Position = new LatLng(longitude, latitude); 
      marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Position)
              .title(pseudo));  
   markers.put(marker.getId(),   "http://"+getString(R.string.ip)+imagePath);

   map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(Position, 15));
     map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
 }
 } catch (JSONException e) {         
 e.printStackTrace();
 }
      } 
   }

       private class CustomInfoWindowAdapter implements InfoWindowAdapter {

            private View view;

            public CustomInfoWindowAdapter() {
                view = 
                   getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info_window,
                        null);
            }

            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

                if (GeolocalisationActivity.this.marker != null
                        &&
                   GeolocalisationActivity.this.marker.isInfoWindowShown()) {
                    GeolocalisationActivity.this.marker.hideInfoWindow();
                    GeolocalisationActivity.this.marker.showInfoWindow();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(final Marker marker) {
                GeolocalisationActivity.this.marker = marker;

                String url = null;

                if (marker.getId() != null && markers != null && markers.size() > 0) {
                    if ( markers.get(marker.getId()) != null &&
                            markers.get(marker.getId()) != null) {
                        url = markers.get(marker.getId());
                    }
                }
                final ImageView image = ((ImageView) 
                       view.findViewById(R.id.badge));

                if (url != null && !url.equalsIgnoreCase("null")
                        && !url.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                    imageLoader.displayImage(url, image, options,
                            new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri,
                                        View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                                    super.onLoadingComplete(imageUri, view,
                                            loadedImage);
                                    getInfoContents(marker);
                                }
                            });
                } else {
                    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                }

                final String title = marker.getTitle();
                final TextView titleUi = ((TextView)
                      view.findViewById(R.id.title));
                if (title != null) {
                    titleUi.setText(title);
                } else {
                    titleUi.setText("");
                }

                final String snippet = marker.getSnippet();
                final TextView snippetUi = ((TextView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.snippet));
                if (snippet != null) {
                    snippetUi.setText(snippet);
                } else {
                    snippetUi.setText("");
                }

                return view;
            }
        }

         private void initImageLoader() {
            int memoryCacheSize;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR) {
                int memClass = ((ActivityManager) 
                        getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE))
                        .getMemoryClass();
                memoryCacheSize = (memClass / 8) * 1024 * 1024;
            } else {
                memoryCacheSize = 2 * 1024 * 1024;
            }

     final ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new 
                 ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
                    this).threadPoolSize(5)
                    .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2)
                    .memoryCacheSize(memoryCacheSize)
                    .memoryCache(new FIFOLimitedMemoryCache(memoryCacheSize-
                                 1000000))
                    .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
                    .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new Md5FileNameGenerator())

                 .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.LIFO).enableLogging() 
                    .build();

            ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
        }
```

Any help please !

Answer (score 0):

The info windows used in Maps API v2 are not "live" views. You're apparently using an ImageLoader to asynchronously setting the ImageView content, and that will not work (because the whole infowindow has been already rendered).

Calling `showInfoWindow()` again when the image arrives should be enough.

From the documentation for [Info Windows](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/infowindows):

> **Note:** The info window that is drawn is *not* a live view. The view is
>   rendered as an image (using `View.draw(Canvas)`) at the time it is
>   returned. This means that any subsequent changes to the view will not
>   be reflected by the info window on the map. To update the info window
>   later (for example, after an image has loaded), call `showInfoWindow()`.